# Flutter: Show data from RestAPI

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show the data from database to Flutter.
I am able to get the data but don't know how can i show it in Flutter. Single data i can show but getting hard time presenting multiple data.

I am using DIO plugin for HTTP requests.

Here is the code.

```
Future getData() async{

    try{  
      dtguid ='34';            
      var bodyss = { "uid" : dtgUid, "deviceid": deviceid};

      Response<Map> responsess =
          await Dio().post("http://192.168.100.4:8080/sampleapp/get-followingdata.php", data: bodyss,);
         Map responseBody = response.data;
        if(responseBodys['success'] == false){

           _showSnackBar(context,responseBody['errors']['inputuid'],Colors.redAccent);

          this.setState((){
            _inProcess = false;
          });

        }else{
          print(responseBody['success']);
          totalcount = responseBody['count'];
          this.setState((){

            _inProcess = false;
          });

        }

    }catch(e){
       print("Exception Caught: $e");
    }

  }
```

Here is the Widget where i need to show this data.

```
Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
               'Test',//  schoolLists[index]['name'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: primary,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Earth',//schoolLists[index]['location'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.school,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Some Data',
                      //schoolLists[index]['type'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

For testing purpose i tried with some hardcoded data `schoolLists` that is working but i don't know how can i show the data from http request.

Sample Data.

```
{"errors":[],
"content":[{"uid":34,"age":35,"name":"Test User 1","country":"India"},
{"uid":34,"age":37,"name":"Test User 2","country":"India"},
{"uid":34,"age":36,"name":"Test User 3","country":"India"}],
"success":true}
```

I need to show name and country to the widget. 
In place of this test value.

```
Text(
               'Test',//  schoolLists[index]['name'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: primary,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
```

Later on i will try to work on Lazyload. Unfortunatly, i am not able to show the data so, didn't asked about the lazyload.

To be honest i am learning Flutter. I don't have much experience in it.

Comment: Are you getting some error or what..what's your issue..!?

Comment: Where are you calling`getData()`..?

Comment: You can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and then in the builder pass the widget you want to show.

Comment: @srikanth7785 Sorry for late reply.  getData is being called during initstate. I can confirm i am getting the data. Just don't know how to show them in the widget. Like Name, Country etc.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta I am facing issue regarding passing the data to Widget.

Comment: You can make a model and from your getData function you can return it. Then use it as future in the FutureBuilder, you can access the data returned by your function as snapshot.data.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta any sample code or link? I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9) should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont see you decoding the body response data
on top of your code first import

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
```

than in your function getData() decode the server JSON response like this

```
//get the json data decode it and store it in decodedResponse
var decodedResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
```

than map thru your decodedResponse as you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think decoding is not needed as DIO plugin handled those.

Comment: can you put some code for this part. "than map thru your decodedResponse as you want" It will be helpful. I am facing issue actually in this part. voted up.

Comment: I haven't created any listview widget. Do i need to create it? If yes, how?

Comment: yes of course you need a list view to map thru the data you getting from your server i see you having only 3 objects (3 users) in your "content":[{ first Object},{ second Object},{ third object}] if you have more objects your list view will map thru every object and populate you users info

Comment: check this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdWhYERuv7g&t=364s

Comment: Exception Caught: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' this is the error i am getting.

Comment: in your code you are passing a <dynamic> to a <Map<dynamic, dynamic>> you have to pass the same type